# NumPy : How to determine the index of the first axis of an ndarray according to some condition?

Tags: numpy, numpy-indexing

Consider the following ndarray `a` -

```
In [117]: a                                                                                          
Out[117]: 
array([[[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[ 3., 11.],
        [ 7., 13.],
        [12., 16.]],

       [[ 0.,  4.],
        [ 6.,  1.],
        [ 5.,  8.]],

       [[17., 10.],
        [15.,  9.],
        [ 2., 14.]]])
```

The minimum computed on the first axis is -

```
In [118]: np.nanmin(a, 0)                                                                            
Out[118]: 
array([[0., 4.],
       [6., 1.],
       [2., 8.]])
```

which is `a[2]` from visual inspection. What is the most efficient way to calculate this index `2`

Comment: There is argmax/argmin are you looking for a more general version?

Comment: Don't think that's `a[2]`. Think you are looking for `np.nanargmin(a,0)`?

Comment: `a[2]` is correct because it has the lowest sum/mean. see result of `np.sum(a,(1,2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by @Divakar you can use [np.nanargmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmin.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan]],

       [[ 3., 11.],
        [ 7., 13.],
        [12., 16.]],

       [[ 0.,  4.],
        [ 6.,  1.],
        [ 5.,  8.]],

       [[17., 10.],
        [15.,  9.],
        [ 2., 14.]]])
minIdx = np.nanargmin(np.sum(a,(1,2)))
minIdx
2
a[minIdx]
array([[0., 4.],
       [6., 1.],
       [5., 8.]])
```